# @yield, @section by php ways in custom framework

Tags: php, laravel, templates, yield

I think that many of you have used laravel framework and know when and how to use @yield, @section.

Now I am writing my own framework and want to implement this feature by **php ways**. I don't want to use any templating scripts (twig, scout or others).

So, how can I implement this feature ?

Comment: Write your own TemplateEngine too.

Comment: I would write it if I need many features of templating. Also if I need much more features of templating I would use twig. But I only need yield, section features (only php ways).

Comment: They are many way to rome, try some and come back if you get stuck. And i thing you can do it, because you want to write an hole framework. SO is mostly for helping when you get stuck while coding, not before.

Comment: The framework is almost ready. But I want to add this feature. Now I am sending meta tags (such as title, description etc) through controller, and for me it's not so good. That's why I want to implement this feature. And I want to know the way how to do it. I will write the code myself. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the way. It can be implemented by using ob_start() ob_get_contents()